# Vb.net Gridview with session variable in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

How do i connect this SQL statement to a gridview? My database is Microsoft Access.

```
Select Posts.[Post_Value], Posts.[Date_Time] FROM
Posts WHERE posts.[user_ID] = '" & Session("user_id") & "'
```

My database connection as a string is this:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data 
Source=" & Server.MapPath("database/Database.mdb")
```

I know i have to open the connection to the database, but what i cant figure out is how to fill the gridview with the data including the session variable? I also want this to happen on page load.

I am doing this in windows visual studio, so if you know what i need to do on the html side aswell that would be a huge help!

This is as far as i have got with my code, but i know its rubbish and may not be anywhere near what i need.

```
Private Sub Page_Load1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" 
    & Server.MapPath("database/Database.mdb")
    Dim strSQL As String = "Select Posts.[Post_Value], Posts.[Date_Time] 
    FROM Posts WHERE posts.[user_ID] = '" & Session("user_id") & "'"
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    connection.CreateCommand()
    Dim oledb As OleDbDataReader(connection)


    Dim dataadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    connection.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "posts")
    connection.Close()
    GridView1.DataSource = ds
    GridView1.DataMember = "posts"
    GridView1.DataBind()


End Sub
```

In case i haven't been clear, what i would like to have at the end of this is: 
- at page load, a gridview will appear with all the posts from the user that is signed in to the session.

Honestly, any pointers would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: VBA has little in common with VB.NET. There are a *lot* of ADO.NET, ASP.NET and data binding tutorials too, going all the way back to 2002.  Start from the tutorials instead of trying code until something works. Your current code for example is vulnerable to SQL injection and converions issues.

Comment: what goes wrong with the code at the moment?